# How to add check boxes to list box items in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to add Check boxes to List Box items so that it would be easy for the Users to select the items and also they can avoid using Control to select multiple items.

How to do this?

I tried CheckBoxListFor but it is not displaying the contents inside the ListBox but displays the check boxes which is not looking good for my requirement.

Comment: Adding `<input type=checkbox/>` in `<select><option>...</option></select>` is not a valid HTML

Comment: Try using [jQuery Choosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

Answer (score 0):

Use html:

```
   <ul>
     <li><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Bike</li>
     <li><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">Car</li>
   </ul>
```

Comment: I want to add checkboxes inside the List Box. I dont think this sample will help Marko. Can you please tell me how it can be done

Comment: How does the listbox html look like? Is it a plain ul-li list? I would do it in static html first and have something to look at. I personally prefer writing plain html instead of these html helper methods. But that of course is a personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you using [JQXListBox](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxlistbox/index.htm), it represents a jQuery listbox widget that contains a list of selectable items. It performs exceptionally well with thousands of items and supports checkboxes, single and multiple selection, keyboard navigation and rich list items visualization.
[image]